# Program with multiple threads always giving same output

Tags: c, multithreading, mutex, thread-synchronization

I'm learning multi-threading and trying to create a program that can print two strings alternately.
I have written the following code :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
pthread_mutex_t lock;
void print(char a[50]){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    printf("%s", a);    //output console is the shared resource
    sleep(2);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
}
void* hello(void* status){
    while(*((char*)status) != '\n'){ 
        print("Hello World\n"); 
    }
}
void* bye(void* status){
    while(*((char*)status) != '\n'){
        print("Goodbye World\n");
    }
}
int main(){
    pthread_t id1, id2;
    char status = '\0';
    int state;
    if (pthread_mutex_init(&lock, NULL) != 0) { 
        printf("\n mutex init has failed\n"); 
        exit(1); 
    }
    printf("Starting Threads (Press Enter to terminate)\n");
    state = pthread_create(&id1, NULL, hello, &status);
    if(state != 0){
        printf("Could not create thread, exiting.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    state = pthread_create(&id2, NULL, bye, &status);
    if(state != 0){
        printf("Could not create thread, exiting.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    scanf("%c", &status);
    printf("Out of The Threads\n");
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&lock); 
    return 0;
}
```

According to what I understand, the mutex should lock the print function once for the hello function and then for the bye function. But I only get this output:

```
Starting Threads (Press Enter to terminate)
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
```

Why does only the hello function get allocated the print function? How do I get it do print both?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will a thread waiting on a mutex get the ownership, immediately after mutex\_unlock() by other thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42428049/will-a-thread-waiting-on-a-mutex-get-the-ownership-immediately-after-mutex-unlo)

Answer (score 0):

Because, you use infinitive `while` in each function `hello` and `bye`. When the first thread starts, it never exits the `while` loop unless you press `enter`.

But when you type `enter`, the loop conditions in all functions will be  `false`, so two threads will never touch `print` function again.

OT, you forget to join the threads.

Try to delete the `while` loop in each function and use it in `main` function, and see what happen. For example the program below (it may be not optimized, but i just want to show why your program always print `Hello World`:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
pthread_mutex_t lock;
void print(char a[50]){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    printf("%s", a);    //output console is the shared resource
    sleep(2);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
}
void* hello(void* status){
   // while(*((char*)status) != '\n'){ 
        print("Hello World\n"); 
    //}
}
void* bye(void* status){
    //while(*((char*)status) != '\n'){
        print("Goodbye World\n");
//    }
}
int main(){
    pthread_t id1, id2;
    char status = '\0';
    int state;
    if (pthread_mutex_init(&lock, NULL) != 0) { 
        printf("\n mutex init has failed\n"); 
        exit(1); 
    }
    printf("Starting Threads (Press Enter to terminate)\n");
    while(status != '\n') {
        state = pthread_create(&id1, NULL, hello, &status);
        if(state != 0){
           printf("Could not create thread, exiting.\n");
           exit(1);
        }
        state = pthread_create(&id2, NULL, bye, &status);
        if(state != 0){
           printf("Could not create thread, exiting.\n");
           exit(1);
        }
        pthread_join(id1, NULL);
        pthread_join(id1, NULL);
        scanf("%c", &status);
    }

    printf("Out of The Threads\n");
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&lock); 
    return 0;
}
```