# C++ shared_lock starvation waiting for excusive lock?

Tags: c++, multithreading, locking

With std::shared_mutex, if a thread is waiting for a exclusive lock, but two other threads are acquiring and releasing a shared lock on this mutex, is it possible for first thread to get starved?

Consider this situation.
Threads 2 and 3 are acquiring and releasing shared locks on the same shared_mutex. The locks always overlap, thus there is no moment when the shared_mutex is unlocked.

Thread 1 then requests a exclusive lock on the same shared_mutex.

Does the request for an exclusive lock prevent a new shared lock from being acquired?
I know if a thread *has* a exclusive lock, no further shared locks can be acquired.
However, the documentation [on cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_mutex) is silent on whether *requesting* a exclusive lock will block requests for a shared lock.

[How to lock std::mutex without starvation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39878090/) indicates that std::mutex doesn't guarantee which thread gets a lock, but does this also apply to std::shared_mutex ?

Comment: I think it depends on how the OS scheduler works. Unless it can guarantee that the thread that has waited the longest is allowed to run when the lock is released, pretty much anything can happen

Comment: the standard provides no guarantee, it's up to your standard library implementation how it works